# How to configure input shape for bidirectional LSTM in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm facing the following issue. 
I have a large number of documents that I want to encode using a bidirectional LSTM. Each document has a different number of words and word can be thought of as a timestep.

When configuring the bidirectional LSTM we are expected to provide the timeseries length. 
When I am training the model this value will be different for each batch.
Should I choose a number for the `timeseries_size` which is the biggest document size I will allow? Any documents bigger than this will not be encoded?

Example config:

```
Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(timeseries_size, encoding_size))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known problem and it concerns both ordinary and bidirectional RNNs. [This discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/85) might help you. In essence, here are the most common options:

- A simple solution is to set the `timeseries_size` to be the max length over the training set and pad the shorter sequences with zeros. [Example Keras code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py#L46). An obvious downside is memory waste if the training set happens to have both very long and very short inputs.
- Separate input samples into buckets of different lengths, e.g. a bucket for `length <= 16`, another bucket for `length <= 32`, etc. Basically this means training several separate LSTMs for different sets of sentences. This approach (known as **bucketing**) requires more effort, but currently considered most efficient and is actually used in the state-of-the-art translation engine [Tensorflow Neural Machine Translation](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to configure the model with a variable length: `input_shape=(None,encoding_size)`.

You will have then to train each document individually.

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for document,output in zip(list_of_documents,list_of_outputs):
        #make sure you have a batch, even if its size is 1
        document.reshape((1,this_doc_length,encoding_size)) 
        output.reshape((1,whatever_output_shape,...))   

        model.train_on_batch(document,output,....)
```

Other options are to use a single input array with the maximum length and add `Masking` layers. (If you're using an `Embedding` layer, it's as easy as making the parameter `mask_zero=True`)

This works pretty well for one-directional LSTMs, but I'm not sure it's correctly implemented for bidirectional (never tested).